# num_rows() function is not working for MSSQL in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, codeigniter

I m using codeigniter with MSSQL db. to get a number of records from a query I m using **$query->num_rows()**. but its not working. If I use MYSQL DB then its working fine. My code is -

```
function getCountry(){

        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->select('CM_CHANNEL_TELCAS_DETAIL.CTD_CNTRY_CODE as CNTRY_CODE, CM_COUNTRY.CC_CNTRY_NAME as CNTRY_NAME');
        $this->db->from('CM_CHANNEL_TELCAS_DETAIL');
        $this->db->join('CM_COUNTRY','CM_CHANNEL_TELCAS_DETAIL.CTD_CNTRY_CODE = CM_COUNTRY.CC_CNTRY_CODE','inner');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        if($query -> num_rows() > 0){    
        return $query->result();
        }else{
          return false;
        }
}
```

If I write above code like this then It gives the results -

```
function getCountry(){

        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->select('CM_CHANNEL_TELCAS_DETAIL.CTD_CNTRY_CODE as CNTRY_CODE, CM_COUNTRY.CC_CNTRY_NAME as CNTRY_NAME');
        $this->db->from('CM_CHANNEL_TELCAS_DETAIL');
        $this->db->join('CM_COUNTRY','CM_CHANNEL_TELCAS_DETAIL.CTD_CNTRY_CODE = CM_COUNTRY.CC_CNTRY_CODE','inner');

        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result();
}
```

I tried to echo ***$query->num_rows()*** value. but its not giving any value. 
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you considered using "mysql_num_rows($query)" ?

Comment: `if($query -> num_rows() > 0){  ` TO `if($query->num_rows() > 0){ ` remove unwanted space...

Comment: $this->db->count_all_results()>0 you can use also this

Comment: mssql_num_rows($query) is this one also. Or you can count simply by any column

Comment: @Maniderapreet Singh, Thanks. Now Its working by using  `$this->db->count_all_results()>0`. Thank u so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with other method `$this->db->count_all_results()`

```
if($this->db->count_all_results() >0)
  {    
    return $query->result();
  }
  else
  {
      return false;
  }
```

Comment: @AmarJyotiChetia happy to help u :)

Comment: Its not giving me the exact number of rows. its giving 1 only.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
echo   $query->affected_rows();
```

hope help youu

Comment: i don't think affected rows works on select query https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html

Comment: affected rows works only for insert and update query.

Comment: The mysqli_affected_rows() function returns the number of affected rows in the previous SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE, or DELETE query.http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_affected_rows.asp @AmarJyotiChetia